# Limits of functions of several variables

Tags: calculus

Compute the following limit:

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Comment: are you familiar with polar conversion?

Comment: Yes. Please let me know...

Comment: Ok, thanks I got it. thanks again.

Comment: If you substitute $x=rcost$ and $y=rsint$ into the problem, what happens?

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos t\\y=r\sin t \end{cases}\implies \frac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=r\cos 2t\xrightarrow[r\to 0]{}0$$

Answer (score 0):

$0\leq|\frac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|\leq\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq |x|+|y|\rightarrow 0 $ when $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$.
Thus, the limit is zero.